# The command 'juju status' can not lookup nodes by name

Tags: juju

Problem:

1) Juju bootstraped successfully (Mass Server and all nodes on VM)

2) I put my maas server ip as name server in resolv.conf , interfaces an hosts file of my juju server but when I try  to "juju status" I get " Lookup N01.maas" :  no such host

3) Here is the temporary solution :

 I put ip and name of nodes in "hosts" file it works

4) How can i fix the problem with nameservers and DNS?

here is error:

root@ubuntu:/etc/network$ juju status 


ERROR state/api: websocket.Dial wss://N01.maas:17070/: dial tcp: lookup N01.maas: no such host

 
ERROR state/api: websocket.Dial wss://N01.maas:17070/: dial tcp: lookup N01.maas: no such host

Comment: Could you post the error message you see or a pastebin link to the actual output of the command?

Answer (score 1):

+1
as a quick and dirty fix - added host to /etc/hosts

Got this: #juju  deploy mysql --show-log --debug

```
2014-05-29 10:39:53 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:297 running juju-1.18.1-trusty-amd64 [gc]
2014-05-29 10:39:53 DEBUG juju api.go:179 no cached API connection settings found
2014-05-29 10:39:53 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:30 opening environment "maas".
2014-05-29 10:39:53 DEBUG juju state.go:75 waiting for DNS name(s) of state server instances [/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-cbc1066-e669-11e3-b5cf-0025900443f2/]
2014-05-29 10:39:53 INFO juju apiclient.go:114 state/api: dialing "wss://100-140.maas:17070/"
2014-05-29 10:39:53 ERROR juju apiclient.go:119 state/api: websocket.Dial wss://100-140.maas:17070/: dial tcp: lookup 100-140.maas: no such host
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the IP and name on hosts and it worked.

/etc/hosts

IP-Address  N01

IP-Address  N01.maas